Python Socket IO Server and React JS Socket IO Client - Missing broadcast messages
I'm having trouble using socketio between python and reactjs. The issue is when I try the code with multiple tabs in same browser or in different browser. Not every client receive the broadcast message. I tried adding forceNew=True and a query parameter with a random number but none of the solution worked.
In python i'm using the below code
    self.sio = socketio.AsyncServer( async_mode='asgi', cors_allowed_origins= settings.CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS )


    @self.sio.event
    async def connect(sid, environ):
        # does nothing now.
        pass

    @self.sio.event
    async def disconnect(sid):
        # does nothing now.
        pass

    @self.sio.event
    async def STOR(sid, data):

        # Broadcast to all
        await self.sio.emit("STOR", json.dumps({
            'success': True,
            'data':{}
        }))
        # acknowledgment to the sender.
        return json.dumps({
            'success': True,
            'data':{}
        } ;


    @self.sio.on('*')
    async def any_event(event, sid, data):
        pass

In react side
    export const socket = io(SOCKET_URL, {
      secure: true,
      forceNew: true,
      transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
      upgrade: true
    });
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleBroadcast = (msg) => {
            //
          }
         socket.on('STOR', handleBroadcast);
         return () => {
         socket.off('STOR', handleBroadcast);
         };
    }, [socket]);

